# QVector::contains fails with checks against constants

Tags: c++, gcc, qt5, qt5.12

Environment as stated in the tags too:

GCC 64bit, Qt 5.12

I have the following example code:

```
// test.h

#include <QVector>

class Test 
{
    Test();

    // Same results with QSet
    const QVector<int> things = {
        BANANA,
        RASPBERRY,
        APPLE,
        -2500,
    };

    const int BANANA = -1000;
    const int RASPBERRY = -2000;
    const int APPLE = -3000;
};
```

```
// test.cpp

#include <QDebug>
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{
    qDebug() << things.contains(APPLE); // false, expected true
    qDebug() << things.contains(-3000); // false, expected true
    qDebug() << things.contains(-2500); // true, expected true
}
```

I don't understand if I've done something wrong in the definitions or I encountered a bug in Qt.

Comment: Can't reproduce (Suse Linux, Qt5.14.1,  g++ 9.2.1).  Please edit your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I supposed tags where enough, added explicit information at the beginning

Comment: How are you verifying the result of `contains`? Did you make sure your program compiles and you're not running an older version of the binary?

Comment: I did a clean run each time to be sure to have the correct results, every iteration I got the "wrong" results

Comment: Fixed the example, thanks to @Amish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I was trying to use constant variables not defined yet

```
// test.h

#include <QVector>

class Test 
{
    Test();

    // Moved them above QVector
    const int BANANA = -1000;
    const int RASPBERRY = -2000;
    const int APPLE = -3000;

    const QVector<int> things = {
        BANANA,
        RASPBERRY,
        APPLE,
        -2500,
    };
};
```

```
// test.cpp

#include <QDebug>
#include "test.h"

Test::Test()
{
    // Now the tests pass as expected
    qDebug() << things.contains(APPLE); // true, expected true
    qDebug() << things.contains(-3000); // true, expected true
    qDebug() << things.contains(-2500); // true, expected true
}
```

Not a bug in QT!